# OS X terminal when enter/exit vim/nano it looks like head/tail the file

Tags: macos, vim, command-line-interface, zsh

[image]

As you can see.

When I exit the vim, back to cli, the file's content follows and only shows me one blank line.

what should I do to avoid this?

I use oh-my-zsh.

Comment: I think it's a zsh-prompt (or git-plugin from oh-my-zsh) issue.

Comment: Your TERM variable is most likely wrong. It should be set to `xterm-256color`